# Debugging multiple static libraries in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have 3 projects in iOS Project 1, Project 2 and Project 3.

Project 1 makes use of the static library of Project 2 and Project 2 makes use of the static library of Project 3.

What I want to do is the put breakpoints in Project 1, 2 and 3 so that i can debug the code of all 3 libraries as I run project 1.

Comment: Throw all projects building these libraries into one single workspace (not project but workspace!).

Comment: If there no other way. I have heard of global breakpoints. Can they be used in this case? If so how?